# In loop cat file - echo name of file - count

Tags: bash, for-loop, scripting

I trying make oneline command with operation where I can do:
in folder "data" have 570 files - each file have some text line - file are called from 1 to 570.txt

I want cat each file, grep by word and count how manny that word occurs.
For the moment he is trying to get this using ' for '

```
for FILES in $(find /home/my/data/ -type f -print -exec cat {} \;) ; do echo $FILES; cat $FILES |grep word ; done |wc -l
```

but if I do that they correctly counts but does not display the counted file

I would like it to look :

```
----> 1.txt <----
210

---> 2.txt <----
15
```

etc, etc, etc..

How to get it

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o word * | uniq -c
```

is practically all you need.

`grep -o word *` gives a line for each hit, but only prints the match, in this case "word". Each line is prefixed with the filename it was found in.

`uniq -c` gives only one line per file so to say and prefixes it with the count.

You can further format it to your needs with awk or whatever, though, for example like this:

```
grep -o word * | uniq -c | cut -f1 -d':' | awk '{print "File: " $2 " Count: " $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
for file in /path/to/folder/data/* ; do echo "----> $file <----" ; grep -c "word_to_count" /path/to/folder/data/$file ; done
```

for loop will ierate over file inside folder "data".
For each of these file, print the name and search for number of occurrence of "word_to_count" (grep -c will directly output a count of matching lines).

Be carefull, if there is more than one iteration of your search word inside a line, this solution will count only one for these iteration.

Comment: You should avoid parsing ls, try `for file in /path/to/folder/data/*` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I change for your solution

Answer (score -1):

Bit of awk should do it?

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' mydatafile
```

Note: some versions of awk have some odd behaviours if you are going to be adding anything exceeding 2^31 (2147483647). See comments for more background. One suggestion is to use `printf` rather than `print`:

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f", s}' mydatafile


$ python -c "import sys; print(sum(int(l) for l in sys.stdin))"
```

If you only want the total number of lines, you could use

```
find /home/my/data/ -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```